Terminology question: philosophic equivalent for oversimplification of assumptions?
There is a trap that a lot of bad philosophers fall into of manipulating a simplified version of a concept and then thinking they have proven the general case. Sometimes they are lucky and that works, or at least works for enough cases to be useful when one remembers the exceptions. (Newtonian physics is incomplete, but works well enough for most applications)
Is there a proper technical term for this class of errors? I presume philosophy has a polite way of telling people to question their assumptions.
(I was reminded of this by the recent discussion of the weaknesses of Pascal's Wager. It makes perfect sense in the limited universe within which he created it, but fails when taken out of that context. And he's a good philosopher; I have seen enough attempts where people crash and burn before they even get onto the runway to sour me somewhat on the whole field. Which makes the fact that I sometimes get up votes here vaguely disturbing.)
((In my original version of this question I compared it to the GIGO problem -- garbage in, garbage out, no matter how correct the operations between the two. But folks have drawn a useful distinction between the two classes of error, so I'm retracting that for clarity.)

Are you trying to say that Newtonian physics is the result of "bad philosophers" who "got lucky"? Newtonian physics was the most accurate model for the observations people had available to them at the time, and it's still exceedingly useful for modelling what happens on Earth. You could say it models behaviour without reflecting the underlying fundamental nature, but that's what science does: it models behaviour, on different scales. We don't have access to the underlying fundamental nature of stuff, and we make better models if we observe behaviour a model doesn't explain.

Faulty (or false) generalization is the fallacy. GIGO though  is quite something else

No. I'm saying that incomplete but correct within its domain as known at the time and extended/refined as the domain expands and new data must be adapted to (physics) is different from something where the author deliberately restricts their domain then conveniently forgets they did so. The latter is what I'm concerned with.

I think the philosophy equivalent of GIGO is a proper logic will give false conclusions from false premises

It is unclear what GIGO as such has to do with oversimplification. To the extent that it points to a fallacy it would be the one of thinking that valid arguments lead to true conclusions ('outputs') without considering whether the premises ('inputs') are true, i. e. whether the arguments are sound. But why should this specifically relate to  premises being oversimplified? They can be 'garbage' for all sorts of other reasons. So oversimplification and GIGO are distinct errors, which one are you asking about?

Apologies if the GIGO reference confuses the issue. I'll edit for clarity.

This is why the scientific method doesn't prove things true -- we understand that our knowledge is generally incomplete. Instead, we make hypotheses and use experiments and observations to see if they're confirmed. The more confirmation they get, the more we trust them to be "good enough".

Can you please give some concrete examples or references of philosophers doing this? -- I'm not doubting that they do - in some way- , but I just think this question is either too trivial or too vague otherwise, and for that reason alone I'd be tempted to vote to close it.

I don't have a specific example in mind; lemme see what I can dig out if the back of my mind. Meanwhile, close as underspecified is fine.

@Rushi: Unless somebody disagrees. I think that is what I was looking for. If you make it an Answer I'll check-mark it.

You ask me to make my comment an answer.
So here it is:
Faulty (or Faulty) Generalization is the one that first came to mind.

But it's not a very exact fit. Here are some others such as

hasty generalization
overextension
conceptual overreach

There are more distant ones that can be related such as reification and confirmation bias
